# Problems pushing local code repository to mercurial project on Google Code

Tags: mercurial, google-code

I have a project that I want to push to a Mercurial repository on Google Code.

I initialized a Mercurial project locally and checked in the code locally.

The only instructions I can find on the Google Code repository are for cloning:

```
hg clone https://blahblah.googlecode.com/hg/ blahblah
```

But I assumed that pushing should be similar.

So I tried:

```
hg push https://blahblah.googlecode.com/hg/ blahblah
```

But I got an error saying "invalid arguments".

**One of the options it provides is "force push". Is this what I need?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to push back a repository that you cloned, try

```
hg push
```

otherwise try

```
hg push https://blahblah.googlecode.com/hg/
```

For future reference, here's the usage information from Mercurial's built-in help system:

```
$ hg help clone
hg clone [OPTION]... SOURCE [DEST]

$ hg help push
hg push [-f] [-r REV]... [-e CMD] [--remotecmd CMD] [DEST]
```

I think the reason `hg push` is failing is because you're giving it too many arguments.

Comment: He's not trying to push back one he cloned.  He's trying to push a repo he created locally.

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'force'.  Force says "and you're allowed to create new remote heads".  You google code has no changesets, so no heads, so you're going from zero to one.  I still wouldn't expect that 'force' is required, but it's definitely worth the try.

Most people starting a repo from scratch would have cloned the empty repo from google (or bitbucket) first, and then made their changes, and then pushed.  I think this is what las3rjock thought you did.